# Extract string from email subject line SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to extract equipment number from the subject line of an email.

I am trying to capture the number behind the last '/' in the subject line but I don't know how to tell SharePoint to look for second '/' and then show the last number of characters... also the equipment number is not fixed, it can be 5 or 9 characters long.

I can't use calculated columns for a number of reasons so I need to do it with SharePoint 2013 workflows.

**Examples of subject lines**

CUSTOMER SERVICE REPORT 43992188 FOR SITE/ EQUIPMENT 42164722 / **42164722**
or 
CUSTOMER SERVICE REPORT 43992188 FOR SITE/ EQUIPMENT 7654 / **7654**

thank you in advance